# add a count of records in existing query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query which gives me the results

```
select status,
       count(errorid) as field1,
       errorid,
       template,
       line,
       error_message,
       error_type,
       max(id) as field2 
FROM errors
GROUP BY status,errorid,template,error_message, error_type,line
ORDER BY field1 desc
```

i am trying to implement the total count of records in it, like the above query has a record of 5000, it should display me 5000 in a separate column , so i can use it, i tried adding count, but the issue is it is counting all 700000 records

Comment: Based on the name of your column, I would *assume* that `errorid` is a unique identifier. Considering that, and that you group in `errorid` I would expect `count(errorid)` to return 1; as there can only be 1 row with that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select status, count(errorid) as field1, errorid, template, line, error_message, error_type,
       max(id) as field2, count(*) over () as num_rows
from errors
group by status, errorid, template, error_message, error_type,line 
order by field1 desc ;
```

It is a bit strange to me that you have `errorid` both as a field and as a `count()`.  That makes sense if you are looking for duplicate errors, but `count(*)` would make the intent clearer.